# Find an upper bound for $T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, summation, upper-lower-bounds

> Find an upper bound for $T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log n$.

Not sure but it looks like the series is:
$$
1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2+\log 1+2^2\log 2+3^2\log 3+...+n^2\log n=\\
=\sum_{i=0}^n i^2+\sum_{i=0}^n i^2\cdot\log i\le n^3+n^3 \log n
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: it is $$T(n-)=T(n-1)+...$$ or $$T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log(n)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  $T(n)=...$, sorry

Comment: The sum should include $T(0)$.

Comment: @Χpẘ doesn't the index run from $0$ to $n$ already?

Comment: @Yos Yes, but the series on the left should already be $T(0)+\dots$. Think of a recursion like $T(n)=T(n-1)+1,T(0)=2$. In this simple case you have $T(1)=3$, not $1$.

Comment: @Ian But at  $T(0)=0$ because $T(0)=T(-1)+0+0$ and of course $T(-1)$ isn't defined because $-1\notin \mathbb N$

Comment: Try $\log (n!)+n^3 \log (n)$ as upper limit

Comment: @Raffaele is this an alternate way of my upper bound or is this the only way? :)

Comment: @Yos $T(0)$ can be defined arbitrarily. Just like in Fibonacci sequence $F_0=1, F_1=1$ are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your upper bound proof looks fine to me.  Assuming $T(0) = 0$, and defining $t(n) = n^2 + n^2 \log n$, I would express your proof as follows.  Because $t(n)$ increases with $n$ for positive integers $n$,
$$T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n t(i) \le n t(n) = n^3 + n^3 \log n.$$

If you want a tighter upper bound, and you're willing to do a little calculus, you can make the following argument.  Because $t(x)$ increases with $x$ for real $x \ge 1$, 
$$T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n t(i) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \int_i^{i+1} t(x)\,dx = \int_1^{n+1} t(x)\,dx.$$
The integral of $t(x)$ is
$$\tau(x) = \int t(x)\,dx = \frac{x^3}{9}\left(2 + 3 \log x \right)+C.$$
Therefore
$$T(n) \le \tau(n+1) - \tau(1) < \frac{(n+1)^3}{9}\left(2+3 \log (n+1) \right).$$

Comment: My guess is that $\log(n)$ here is $\log_2(n)$, which will change your constants

Comment: Oh, log base 2...  Okay, for an arbitrary base $b$ the upper bound would be $(n+1)^3 ((3-\log_b e) + 3 \log_b(n+1))/9$.