# How to find a lower bound for $T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log n$?

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

> How to find a lower bound for $T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log n$?

This question is in continuation to the following one :
[Find an upper bound for $T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2+n^2\log n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357500/find-an-upper-bound-for-tn-tn-1n2n2-log-n)

For upper bound the logic is to "round" the indices towards $n$, but I really don't have a clue how to go about the lower bounds.

Comment: How tight should the bound be ? Otherwise you could simply use $1 \leq \log(n)$ (for $n \geq e)$ and solve the reccurence and handle the first case for small $n$ "manually".

Comment: @Zubzub it should be $\Theta$ in big-O notation. Can you please show an example of how handle small $n$ "manually"?

Comment: Ah ok if you want asymptotics, sure we don't really care about the first term $T(1), T(2), ...$. So you already have an upperbound of $O(n^3 \log n)$. However using the inequality I suggested ( $1 \leq \log(n)  $), you get $\Omega(n^3)$ so you cannot conclude any $\Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: $$T(n)=T(0)+\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\log (ek)\geqslant\sum_{k=n/2}^n(n/2)^2\log(en/2)\geqslant(n/2)(n/2)^2\log(n)=\Theta(n^3\log n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the previous question I restate the summation and I assume that you are looking for an asymptotic lowerbound $T(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ and since in the previous question you already obtained $T(n) = O(n^3 \log n)$ we will aim for the same lowerbound.

$$
T(n) = \overbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2}^{\Omega(n^3)} + \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \log(i) \overset{(*)}{\geq} \Omega(n^3) + \frac{n}{2}\left((\frac{n}{2})^2\log(n/2) \right) = \Omega(n^3\log(n))
$$
$(*)$ The trick is to retain only half of the term in the sum and lowerbound them by the central term. For example, assuming $f(n)$ is positive and increasing, then $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) \geq f(3) + f(3)$ (we throw away $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ which creates a lowerbound on the sum and we then lowerbound the remaining term ($f(3)$ and $f(4)$) by the smallest remaining term which is $f(3)$. More generally $\sum_i^n f(i) \geq \frac{n}{2} f(n/2)$.

Comment: How do we know that we can retain $\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: All terms are positive in the sum. So if I remove half of them, I will lowerbound the sum !

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, $$T(n)=T(0)+\sum^n_{k=1}(k^2+k^2\log k).$$ Now we know that $$\sum^n_{k=1}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=f(n).$$ Then, by partial summation,
$$\sum^n_{k=1}k^2\log k=\sum^n_{k=1}[f(k)-f(k-1)]\log k=f(n)\log(n+1)-\sum^n_{k=1}f(k)\log\left(1+\frac1{k}\right),$$ and since $\log\left(1+\frac1{k}\right)<\frac1{k},$
$$\sum^n_{k=1}k^2\log k\ge f(n)\log(n+1)-\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{f(k)}{k}=f(n)\log(n+1)-\frac1{6}\left(2f(n)+3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n\right)$$
I think the rest should be clear.